# Highlighting text without highlighting/selecting the entire element - is it possible to avoid dummy elements?

Tags: javascript, css, user-experience

**The Goal:** to only highlight text, not whitespace.

Highlighting the entire element, to me, can result in some unruly and poor UX when large paddings, line-heights, etc. are implemented (whitespace that is now highlightable). A task as simple as highlighting a block of text may in turn highlight other regions of the website that weren't intended by the user. I'm trying to resolve this on my current site but have only been able to achieve it by using the method provided below.

In which, I use an inline element inside a block-level element. Which, as you may notice, could get very cumbersome and code heavy if used throughout a website. Is there a better way to achieve the 2nd method?

*I'm open to Javascript solutions as well as CSS.*

To my knowledge (via testing) it doesn't render differently if copied+pasted in to a word doc or web mail application such as gmail. If you know of any issues this may cause, please mention it below.

**To better illustrate:**

With Highlight improvements:
[image]
Without Highlight improvements:
[image]

^ *Granted this is a half ass'd exampled, it demonstrates one of the instances where it can come in handy, there are a plethora of others, trust me.*

```css
.highlight-text-only > *{
display:block;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
   -o-user-select: none;
      user-select: none}

.highlight-text-only *>span,
.highlight-text-only *>strong{
display:inline;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
 -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
   -o-user-select: text;
      user-select: text}
```

```html
<div class="highlight-text-and-element">
  <h3>Testing Text Selection Method 1 (default)</h3>
  <div>of only text</div>
  <a href="#"><strong>with</strong></a>
  <p>highlighting</p>
  <span>the actual elements</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="highlight-text-only">
  <h3><span>Testing Selection Method 2</span></h3>
  <div><span>of only text</span></div>
  <a href="#"><strong>without</strong></a>
  <p><span>highlighting</span></p>
  <span><span>the actual elements</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't target text nodes in the DOM directly using CSS, but you can find them with javascript and programmatically wrap them in `<span>`s to achieve the same effect while keeping your markup clean:

```js
function wrapText(nodes, className) {
  for (var i=0,len=nodes.length; i<len; i++) {
    var node=nodes[i];
    
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var wrapper=document.createElement("span");
      wrapper.className = className;
      node.parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper,node);
      wrapper.appendChild(node);
    } else {
      wrapText(node.childNodes, className);
    }
  }
}

wrapText(document.querySelectorAll(".highlight-text-only"),"selectme");
```

```css
.highlight-text-only {
  -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.highlight-text-only .selectme {
  -webkit-user-select: text; -moz-user-select: text; -ms-user-select: text; -o-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight-text-and-element">
  <h3>Testing Text Selection Method 1 (default)</h3>
  <div>of only text</div>
  <a href="#"><strong>with</strong></a>
  <p>highlighting</p>
  <span>the actual elements</span>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="highlight-text-only">
  <h3>Testing Selection Method 2</h3>
  <div>of only text</div>
  <a href="#"><strong>without</strong></a>
  <p>highlighting</p>
  <span>the actual elements</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @darcher not sure if you've seen this yet, but in case you're already using the previous version of the script, I improved it significantly since my initial post

Comment: I see that, I like this method, I'll probably target specific querySelectors `h3, p` etc. and target the first decendent `*>span` of each element type to keep things a little semantically sound. But this is great. Thank you very much, just what I was looking for. Coding this into all the razor files for our CMS would have been a nightmare. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.highlight-text-only {
    color: orange;
}

.highlight-text-only span {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:blue;
    font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<hr>

<div class="highlight-text-only">
  <h3>Testing Selection Method</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam pretium commodo nulla, sit amet rutrum nibh pretium eget. Aliquam vitae <span>egestas</span> nisi, vitae aliquam risus. <span>Suspendisse</span> potenti. Mauris iaculis ligula ultricies cursus tincidunt. Ut risus tellus, maximus at metus et, posuere accumsan dolor. Nunc ut augue est. Phasellus euismod felis quis quam fringilla, quis varius ligula commodo. Curabitur ante ligula, scelerisque vel auctor et, imperdiet non odio. Proin ac sapien sed est efficitur pretium vel id elit. Praesent volutpat, nisi et pharetra interdum, enim orci tincidunt urna, vel accumsan nulla mi vel ligula. <span>Mauris</span> augue quam, placerat eget posuere non, imperdiet nec purus. Praesent nisl nisl, venenatis in erat eget, euismod dapibus metus.</p>
</div>
    
<hr>
```

I'm not sure if you just want a lite code option and with no underline.
Take a look at this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/jc3mmd8L/1/)** to see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm after. If you highlight the two sections with your mouse in my fiddle, you'll see one highlights the entire block level element, and the 2nd method only highlights the inline text. I'm looking for a method in doing this that doesn't revolve around layering every block of text that I wish to be selectable. The whitespace has the possibility of overlapping other elements and highlighting regions on a webpage that weren't intended. I'll probably just inject the inline elements with javascript or something of the sort.